# Is there a parameter to make my app keeping status a while in memory?

Tags: ios

Is there a parameter to make my app keeping status a while in memory?

Now if I press the home button, it will exit fully.
If I run the app again, it will restart.

I prefer the app keeping status a while in memory

Comment: I see you unaccepted my answer, are you still having issues that your app doesn't stay in memory when pressing the home button?

Answer (score 0):

By default iOS will pause an app's execution after it has entered the background (by pressing the home button for example). When you then reopen the app, i.e. bring the app into the foreground, it will continue where it left of (the app hasn't been killed). However, if the system runs out of memory due to the memory usage of other apps, iOS could kill your app and opening it again will be the same as a fresh start you would get after swiping the app up in the app switcher.

If just going to the home screen and opening the app again causes the app to restart, it may be that you have set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in the 'Info.plist' file to `YES`. If you remove the entry or set it to `NO`, you should get the default behavior as described above.